# Apache mod_rewrite specific dynamic url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, syntax-error

I am using mod_rewrite to write domain.com/index.php?=string to domain.com/string. I need to have the website display the index.php?=sitemap when a robot goes to sitemap.html for SEO purposes. I have tried lots of variations and have gotten /sitemap to show /sitemap.html using the code:

```
    RewriteRule ^sitemap/?$ http://www.domain.com/sitemap.html [R]
```

The rewrite understandably does not fix the issue however because it actually is looking for sitemap.html not index.php?p=sitemap.

The rules currently in place are:

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1& [L,NC]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is this normal ? `?=sitemap` I always use it as `?p=sitemap` or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this inbetween both of your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.html$ index\.php?p=sitemap [L]
```

So it all looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.html$ index\.php?p=sitemap [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1& [L,NC]
```